# Sorting a column by percentage in Datatables that also contains html

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a table with a ton of percentages. I use [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) to sort most of my table and if you check the right most column [HERE](http://fantasymls.net/theme/index.php), the text based percentages do sort correctly.

The problem is... I want to remove that and replace it with the CSS bars to the left of that (2nd right most column). I cannot get these CSS bars to sort with DataTables at all.

Here is the code I use in each `<td>`...

```
<div id="positive">
    <div class="anim" style="width:27%;">
        <div class="text">27.05%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the code in the Percentage section on [HERE](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) to get the percentage to sort on the right-most column.

Any idea how I can get DataTables to ignore all the HTML tags in my above code and sort just by the percentage?

Thanks for any help you can give, and please let me know if you need more info.

**EDIT1:** Here is the code used for sorting text percentages

```
    jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, 
        {
        "percent-pre": function ( a ) 
            {
            var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace( /%/, "" );
            return parseFloat( x );
            },

        "percent-asc": function ( a, b ) 
            {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
            },

        "percent-desc": function ( a, b ) 
            {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
            }
        } );
```

And here are the options I use for Datatables on that page (I can change stuff if needed).

**EDIT2:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#gradient-style').dataTable( 
            {
            "bPaginate": true,
            "aaSorting": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": '<"H"lf>rt<"F"ip>',
            "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 6 ] } ],

            "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "percent" },
            { "sType": "percent" } ]
            } );
        } );
```

**EDIT3: SOLVED IT**

Here's what I did... Go to [this page](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting). Merge the 
`Numbers with HTML` with the `Percentage`. Here's the code I changed in my edit1 code.

```
            /* This cuts out the HTML */
            var x = String(a).replace( /<[\s\S]*?>/g, "" );
            return parseFloat( x );
            /* This takes what's left, removes the % sign and sorts by that */
            var y = (x == "-") ? 0 : x.replace( /%/, "" );
            return parseFloat( y );
```

Comment: It will be better if you can post the config of you datatables, I mean the options of datatables.

Comment: @OQJF The DataTables options have been added and also the code I used to sort just text percentages. Thanks.

Comment: Great I'm checking it now, that's complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2014:

From [the docs](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/num-html):

> DataTables 1.10+ has HTML numeric data type detection and sorting abilities built-in. As such this plug-in is marked as deprecated, but might be useful when working with old versions of DataTables.

#### Deprecated Answer:

I check the [Url](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) that you posted and found something new that: Numbers with HTML , did you try it. According to the document that it will strip the html tag and sort just with the number.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "num-html-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x = String(a).replace( /<[\s\S]*?>/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( x );
    },

    "num-html-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "num-html-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

Comment: Never mind buddy, seems you need to combine those two ways to fix the problem. And the greatest thing is that your question also gives me opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: Sorted it thank you. I used the code to strip html, then fed that into the sort by percentage code and it worked first time. Far easier than I expected it to be. The answers were already there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a non-programming solution to this problem.

In finance and many other fields of work, it is common to put the unit (%, $, €) in the header row of the table. Repeating the symbol on every row is useless and might make your page slightly less readable than without.

Just consider this option and your sorting issues will vanish.

Comment: So simple, but also ideal for someone new looking to avoid hassle. Thanks for the suggestion, I got it working as above though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['num-sort'] = function(oSettings, iColumn) {
        var aData = [];
        $('td:eq(' + iColumn + ')', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings)).each(function() { aData.push($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')); });

        console.log(aData);
        return aData;
    }
```